# application stops without giving en error like application has been stopped

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

i have more than 35 fragments in one activity calling.
may it possible that my application stops at run time without giving an

- APPLICATION HAS BEEN STOPPED 
  error?
  please solve my query...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your "query". Yes it's possible an application stops without giving That error. Like for example:

- When you exit it
- When the system closes it